# ARM platform specific Qmake.bin

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, arm, embedded-linux

I have been trying to develop a GUI using Qt on STM32MP157C-DK2 as provided by STMicroelectronics.
I am using the SW suite which is given by them i.e https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stm32mp1dev.html
y query revolves around the issue where-in i am trying to configure a Qt project for this field
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbtVN.png)

I can seem to find qmake.bin specific to ARM architecture.
If i do `qmake --version` on my linux host i get o/p as

```
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.12.8 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

But if i used this qmake.bin for configuration then QT complains that it is not able to find compatability between the target compiler configuration and current qmake which is 64-bit linux based.

From where i can get a qmake.bin for my stm32mp1 platform ? Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need more than `qmake`.  Qmake is a tool to automate building Qt projects.  You can use plain makefiles, cmake, etc.  Qmake eases cross-platform builds and makes it simpler to use `moc`, `rcc`, etc. build time tools that Qt projects may require.  However, there is a more important point that you need Qt libraries built for your environment (CPU, libc, OS, graphics stack, I/O devices).  Either you need to configure and build Qt from source or you need to find these pre-built, which is not a good stack overflow question, and relies on someone else to have accomplished the prior.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will take a look and see what can be done.